# What is better for Image Processing learning/prototyping Mathematica or Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I am learning Image processing/Pattern recognition. My background is C++ and basics in OpenCV.
I am looking for a tool to learn how to test all the filters and algorithms on my images easier. Are Matlab and Mathematica suitable for this? If so, which one is better?

Thank you!

Comment: You may also consider using scipy/numpy: http://scipy-lectures.github.com/advanced/image_processing/index.html

Comment: up: Thanks, looks very interesting! If this would be in "answers" section, I would have selected this. (Just got a little bit frustrated from Mathematica syntax)

Answer (score 5):

You can do great image processing in both languages, so there is no general answer to this question.

In your specific case, assuming that you have access to all the relevant toolboxes of both packages, I recommend Matlab, since its syntax is more similar to C++ than Mathematica's functional syntax. Consequently, Matlab may be easier for you to pick up. Note that many filters are already implemented in Matlab, and I assume also in Mathematica.

One of the Matlab blogs has just started a series on [image filters](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2012/11/13/image-effects-part-1/). Also, you could try and adjust the [MorphTool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23697-morphtool) from the File Exchange to be able to play with the filters you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Actually, OpenCV provides a similar tool in examples for closing/opening/erosion/etc. On Mathematica's website there is an impressive documetation of the features, which openly explain the algorithms and the knowledge could be used tool-box independently: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImageProcessing.html .

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: Matlab's documentation is quite nice as well, and since many of the toolbox functions are written in Matlab, you can look at the source code to find out how it's done.